# Edge Dev Channel's Console is blank and unaccessible

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

A Picture speaks a thousand words:
[image: The Edge Console on the Dev Channel is completely blank]

I'm using the latest Microsoft Edge Dev Channel (v91.0.831.1 right now), and for some weeks till now the console is completely blank and unaccessible. I have tried:

- Opening on anonymous mode
- Opening via powershell by executing `msedge.exe --safe-plugins` on the dev channel msedge
- Disabliong all extensions
- Restoring DevTools defaults through the devtools preferences
- Restoring the Edge browser defaults through edge://settings/reset
- going to devtools://devtools and cleaning local storage

I'm hoping someone else went through this already. Maybe there's some other corrupted configuration I'm not aware of that I can reset?

For the record, the console is working fine on regular Edge(v89), only the Dev Channel version seems to have this problem.

Comment: Are you running Edge Dev on Windows 10? I test the same version of Edge Dev on Windows 10 20H2 and Console works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mpqA.gif. You can try to reinstall Edge Dev to see if it can solve the issue. Please remember to choose **Also clear your browsing data** when you uninstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug on Edge Dev and was fixed today
[image: Improvements this week include a fix for a blank F12 console]